# Сделать одинаковую высоту элементов

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.bgr1 {
  background: rgb(109, 166, 165);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 17vh;
  background-size: cover;
}

.bgr2 {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 183vh;
  background-size: cover;
}

.btn {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 169px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: .8em 1em calc(.8em + 3px);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: rgb(62, 134, 146);
}


/*font sans-serif*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Main</title>
  <link href="~/Content/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="bgr1">

      <img src="~/pictures/report.png" alt="альтернативный текст">

      <a class="btn" href="@Url.Action(" Main ","Home ")">Про сервіс</a>
      <a class="btn" href="@Url.Action(" Main ","Home ")">Можливості</a>
      <a class="btn" href="@Url.Action(" Main ","Home ")">ЕЦП</a> @*
      <a class="btn" href="@Url.Action(" Main ","Home ")">Ціна</a>
      <a class="btn" href="@Url.Action(" Main ","Home ")">Контакти</a>*@
    </div>

    <div class="bgr2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как поднять кнопки и растянуть их на высоту контейнера Report

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для начала покажите ваш `HTML` и `CSS`.

Comment: правиииииииииил

Comment: На высоту контейнера Report — это на высоту изображения или на высоту всей бирюзовой обертки?

Comment: на высот бирюзовой обертки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно задать

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

для этого, но там у вас куча дополнительных свойств, так что до хорошего вида придется еще переписать много чего.

Comment: добавил ещё margin-bottom:100px;  и все стало на место, спасибо)